# Torrent upload ratio not updated on Synology DS212+

Tags: networking, nas, bittorrent, nat, synology

I have a Synology DS212+ NAS running DSM 4.2-3211 (current version). I use it for several purposes including torrent download using Download Station and a tracker that needs authentication.

My problem is that my download/upload ratio isn't updated, so it constantly falls down.

My NAS is behind a router, and I configured the NAT to forward ports 6890 to 6999 to the internal IP address of the NAS.

Here are the Download Station settings :

- TCP port : 6990,
- Sharing ratio : 900%,
- Sharing time : infinite,
- max download speed : 0 (no limit),
- max upload speed : 0 (no limit),
- BT protocol encryption : checked,
- max numbers of peers allowed by torrent file : 4000,
- DHT : checked, with port 6889.

When the DHT option is not checked, the NAS doesn't upload any files. I don't know what is this option for.

Can someone help me to solve this problem ? Did I miss any step, or does it come from the NAT ? How is the authentication managed by Dowload Station ?

(Sorry for my english) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your configuration is OK.

The solution could be to configure the option that stop to seed files when they are completed.

Go to configuration option of the Download Station, menu BT, in the section "Stop Task Automatically", and in the second combo box (propagating time...) select "Forever".